# Disabling column header in datagridview C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview 'audit_TrailDataGridView'. I need to disable the column headers of this i.e: nothing should happen when user clicks on the column headers.

```
private void audit_TrailDataGridView_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
         {
            //do what?

         }
```

Please help.

Comment: currently, what is happening when you click on the column headers?

Comment: What currently happens when you click the column?

Comment: It is causing an unexpected error 'Invalid Exception' and the application stops. I am not sure what causes the error (even after much debugging), but it occurs only when the user clicks on the column header of the last column on the datagridview. So , I am trying to disable the user from being able to click.

Comment: The "Related" column has a lot of questions that seem to be very similar.  Have you checked those?  If those don't answer your question, could you please post the exact error message and stack trace?

Comment: Classic example of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), by the way.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that something undesirable happens because when a user clicks on a header an event is raised intended to handle the situation when a user clicks on an actual cell, not a header (for example, the `CellDoubleClick` event). You need to manually check inside all such events that the cell clicked is not a header:

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
 {
     if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
     {
         //do something here
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with `dataGridView1_SelectionChanged` event.

I wanted the DataGridView to be sorted when the header columns clicked, but not implement the code that I wanted to be runned for non-header row clicks.

So basically I found a stupid solution, I added a huge `try catch` block inside `dataGridView1_SelectionChanged` method containig everything in this method.

Maybe this will work for you or someone else too.